# how to get multiple sets of distinct values

Tags: sql-server, ssis

This is not about distinct combinations of values (Select distinct col1, col2 from table)

---

I have a table with a newly loaded csv file.

Some columns are linked to foreign key dimensions but the values in a given column may not exist in the reference tables.

My desire is to find all the values in each column that do not exist but in such a way as to minimize the amount of table scans in our source table.

My current approach consumes the output of a bunch of queries like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM table WHERE col2 NOT IN (SELECT val FROM DimCol2)
SELECT DISTINCT col3 FROM table WHERE col3 NOT IN (SELECT val FROM DimCol3)
```

however, for N columns, this results in N table scans.

*Table* is up to 10M rows and columns range in cardinality from 5 through to 5M, but almost all values are already present in the dim tables (>99%).

*DimColN* ranges in size from 5 values to 50M values, and is well indexed.

The csv is loaded into table via SSIS, so splitting pre-processing inside SSIS is possible, but i would have to avoid a sql query for each row.

The ssis server does not have enough spare ram to cache all the dim tables.

Comment: The values in a given column may not exist in the reference table. My desire is to find all the values in each column that do not exist but in such a way as to minimize the amount of table scans in our source table? I'm trying but feeling that I am failing to restate your question.

Comment: @billinkc that is a correct re-statement of my question, i'll try to clarify my wording.

Comment: Why don't you start by importing the changes to the reference tables, so that all the foreign key values will exist in them when you import the fact table?

Answer (score 0):

What about using a `LEFT JOIN` and checking where the results of the join are null, meaning they don't exist in DimCol2

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col2
FROM table a
LEFT JOIN DimCol2 on a.Col2 = b.val
WHERE b.val IS NULL
```

Comment: yes, i believe that approach would allow you to reduce the size of the problem to only those rows that have at least 1 new value  ( SELECT DISTINCT Col2,col3,col4,...
FROM table a
LEFT JOIN DimCol2 b on a.Col2 = b.val LEFT JOIN DimCol3  con a.Col3 = c.val LEFT JOIN DimCol4
WHERE b.val IS NULL or c.val is null or d.val is nul... ) and you end up getting all the combinations with at least 1 new val.

Comment: might be worth checking the execution plans, and possibly posting them here so we can see where the bottlenecks are